# plugin translation is not working

Tags: plugins, translation

im working on translating a wordpress theme, i have translate all the language files even the related plugins files but then when i apply on my theme the words in my plugins langage files are not translated while the words located in my theme langage file are translated; here is a screenshot of one page that show the issue
[image]
here is a screenshot of the plugin language folder
[image]
and this is for theme language folder

[image]

Comment: Please show all a reduced test case of your code so that someone might be able to debug and test it. Screenshots can be a great supplement to code, but they are not a replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fix this just put renaming the languages files in the plugin to `realia-ar.po` and `realia-ar.mo`